# How to loop through requests and find the first error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

I am trying to write the javascript version of this [Github bash script](https://github.com/b3n-j4m1n/salary-seeker/blob/master/salary-seeker.sh)

I need a for loop to go through an API endpoint and find the first response with the result '0'.

The API URI stays the same but has an increasing query string `salaryrange`.

I have tried to code this but it appears to be in async.

```
function seekSalaryFinder() {
  var min = 30000
  var max = 200000
  var salary = min;
  for (t = 0; t <= 30; t++) {
    var salary = salary + 10000
    var apiEndpoint = 'https://chalice-search-api.cloud.seek.com.au/search?jobid='
    var jobId = 38300301
    var url = apiEndpoint + jobId + "&salaryrange=" + salary
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      var array = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(array.totalCount)
    });
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me and explain to me what would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Easiest way, make the function `async`, then `await` each promisified request inside the loop, and see if it's result is `0`

Comment: Would it be best to do it in series and find the *first* one that's '0' ? Obviously I need to get the lowest upper limit.

Comment: That's exactly what my suggestion is describing - `await` inside a `for` loop will wait for each response in serial